# CMake <cmath> header errors on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

I updated my MacOS to 10.15.4, and Xcode to 11.4.1. I had a CMake project compiling and working perfectly fine before this update.

Now I get errors in the cmath header regarding namespace definitions:

[image: cmath header file]

Note: this is the screenshot of the standard cmath header file. It is not my code.

I created a command line tool project with C++ on Xcode and included cmath and had it compile successfully. Therefore there is some issue with the CMake generated Xcode project.

I am using C++14. Nothing has changed in my CMakeLists.txt. It was compiling without issue before. I cleared the cache and rebuilt the project - still no luck.

I am using CMake 3.17.1, and have reinstalled Xcode, and the command line tools as well. No luck  at all. Frustrating to see an update break my project.

Edit: I found the issue: the following lines are the cause of the compilation error:

```
find_package(PCL 1.8 REQUIRED COMPONENTS common io visualization filters registration)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
```

Removing these lines from my CMakeLists.txt fixes the issue for some reason. My PCL install was installed via brew and is the latest version.

Comment: What happens if you include <math.h>?

Comment: @DanM. Tried that too. Included <math.h> in my source files before cmath and still the same error.

Comment: does <math.h> work on its own? Without cmath? Does this also happen for some simple barebones project (basically only main.cpp with includes and int main())?

Comment: @DanM. Ok, simple CMake project works... So I decided to compare and after some trial and error with adding dependencies to the barebones cmake project - it turns out including the point cloud library causes this error.

Comment: I suggest you raising this issue on brew/PCL (at least they are better suited to diagnose it). I hope pcl doesn't contain a math.h header (or does it? That'd explain the weirdness) ;P. In the meantime, I doubt it'd help (although you never know), but I've noticed that you use old style include_*/link)* etc. I suggest you switch to target-based alternatives instead, i.e. `target_{include|link}_directories` and `target_compile_definitions`.

Comment: @DanM.Will do. Thank you very much for the suggestion and help.

Comment: Don't forget to post an answer if you figure out the root cause and the proper solution.